# Cropit and Laravel 5. How to upload cropped image to a server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, crop

How can I upload jQuery cropped image to a server? After cropping an image I get that long DataURI string. I am using jQuery Cropit plugin and laravel 5.4. Or maybe there are more useful plugin than Cropit and is easier to work with uploads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I'm using Intervetion package you can crop rezize.. It is simple to use check the laravel version Here : http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel
Good Luck

Comment: Yes I know, but the functionality I need is that website user crops image in the front end and laravel should save it as the user wanted it to look like.

Comment: Check out this example : https://sidharath.com/blog/97/jquery-cropper-with-Laravel using jQuery Cropper

Comment: This helped. Thanks.